# Pyspark sumbit - how to run packages before running sparksubmit --py-files

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-submit

In azure Databricks, while sparksubmit --py-files , how to run the package azure.storage.blob before running the main.py

Input:
["--py-files","dbfs/mnt/blob/offline_aggregation_job.zip","/dbfs/mnt/blob/offline_aggregation_job/main.py"]

Output:
file "/dbfs/mnt/blob/offline_aggregation_job/main.py", line 21, in

from s3_logger.s3log_handler import S3LoggerHandler

File "/dbfs/mnt/blob/offline_aggregation_job/s3_logger/s3log_handler.py", line 4, in

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.